# Selenium/chrome driver keeps crashing "Chrome failed to start: exited normally" and "DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist"

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver, undetected-chromedriver

I am trying to run my script for selenium/chromedrive but keep getting the error below.

Selenium ver 4.72
Chrome Browser version:Version 108.0.5359.125 (Official Build) (64-bit)
ChromeDriver version: ChromeDriver 108.0.5359.71

> Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
> (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
> (The process started from chrome location C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)

> **Script**:
> from selenium import webdriver
> from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
> from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
> from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
> options = Options()
> options.binary_location = "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe"
>
> options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
> s = Service(executable_path=r'C:/Bin/chromedriver.exe')
> driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
> driver.get("https://www.walmart.com")

Thanks you for any help

I have also tried Selenium manager but no good. I'm at my wits end

I think it might be because my chrome is installed in Application folder instead of user/appdata? Not too sure. What is the default location for Chrome? I've tried uninstialling chrome/and appdata and reinistalling but it puts me back at that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I got same error.
If you dont want to use option --headless
You Should try this,
Before executing the code, close all the chrome browser windows and try. –

Comment: This helped me in February 2024.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with the latest chromedriver according to this thread: https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/wYA8JQB7l0A

Try running in headless mode and it will spin up properly.

Answer (score 0):

Same here - Bug still there in chrome/chromedriver V110.XXXX @ 14 Feb2 023
Disable the option --headless, that seems to work.